# Rdlc report with matrix in Visual Studio 2013 report viewer seems to cause problems

Tags: matrix, visual-studio-2013, pivot-table, rdlc

I have a report that contains a Matrix with one row group and one column group. When my reports contains many rows, the columns group of the first page are sized correctly. If I have to many columns, they too are sized correctly on the second page.

However, my second set of pages and after have larger columns, which in some case, splits the columns into two pages instead of keeping them together like it's supposed to.

I'm a little at a lost since I can't figure out what is happening.

When I export the report to Excel, I can't see any problem. However, should I export to pdf, I see the same problem

As you can see, the pdf page 2 version have more spaces at the end of each column. However, the rdlc definition does not have such spacing and the number is right aligned to the border, so it doesn't make any sense to me. Could this be a bug in report viewer 2013?

[image: Excel (No problem]

[image: PDF : Page 1]

[image: PDF : Page 2]

Comment: we had a similar, in our case some borders disapeare in PDF and on the printer , the problem wasn't the report instead it was the PDF-Viewer and the printer Driver so if you get the right result in atleaste 1 Formate (Excel,Word,PDF,ReportViewer) the problem is based on my experience not your report.

Comment: I rebuilt it from scratch and was able to make it work OK by ajusting the grouping and inline tables, so in the end it did work out for me. However, the problem will still exist if I use the same method...